# Disable fstab error message at startup when to-be-mounted drive not found

Tags: 14.04, boot, xubuntu, startup, fstab

### Issue

I configured fstab to mount my sd card as /backup automatically at startup. But everytime fstab doesn't find the sdcard, it gets stuck at the xubuntu 14.04 bootscreen waiting for the user to press A (continue without sdcard) or M (retry mounting).

fstab to mount sd card

> /dev/mmcblk0p1 /backup vfat comment=x-gvfs-show,users,uid=1000,auto 0
>   0

### Needs

Is there a possibility to skip this error message screen even if sdcard is not found/cannot be mounted, so that the user can startup xubuntu without any holdups?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to `man fstab`, you can add the mount option `nofail`. If I recall correct this works for that situation (I did it once, years ago).

Comment: hi there thanks for your reply, but somehow `nofail` doesn't work in 14.04 Xunbuntu. Instead I tried with `nobootwait` which worked.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

since Xubuntu 14.04 doesn't react to `nofail`, there is a workaround with `nobootwait`. See bug report:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/610869

Updated example:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /backup vfat comment=x-gvfs-show,users,uid=1000,nofail,nobootwait,auto 0 0
```